# how to insert data into database on clicking an image using php

Tags: php, mysql, image, insert

i'm making a music website.
i have this button image for adding a song to playlist. if a user clicks on that button,it should enter that songs details into my playlist table.
i know how to submit information to database using text boxes.
can anybody help me with the code for it?
**what should be the IF condition for clicking of the image/button?**

Comment: What have you tried? What is your proposed request/response architecture?  Are you planning to do this using AJAX?

Comment: What do you mean by "if condition" ? Anyway, you could use a link for hwat you're trying to do; using AJAX, maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two ways:

1) using a regular HTML form. Wrap the form around your button image, put a hidden field in the form with the song details e.g. `<input type="hidden" name="song" value="Where the streets have no name">` then when the form is submitted your will have the details of that song. Use more than one hidden field if you have to.

2) a little more complicated but it would be ideal to use Ajax. You could collect the song details from the image id attribute and then push it all to a PHP page.

Comment: Or you could wrap the image in a link and use its href; it would degrade better in case of javascript not working (I'm talking about your 2nd option)